# Relative Layout alignment

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have used Relative layout with some views. I need to align the views in horizontally, but the views are not displaying same in all the screen size devices?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:background="#007DD7">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1_login"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowRadius="10.0"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/1_line"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="@+id/text1_login"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1_delivery"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:shadowRadius="10.0"
            android:text="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2_delivery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1_delivery"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:text="Delivery"
            android:textColor="@color/add_contact_selected"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/2_line"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="@+id/text1_delivery"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="215dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1_payment"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowRadius="10.0"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2_payment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1_payment"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:text="Payment"
            android:textColor="@color/add_contact_selected"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Put the screenshot that what you actually want and what your are getting right now with this layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` and play with `android:layout_weight` to allign your views.

I've edited your code:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:background="#007DD7"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1_login"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:shadowRadius="10.0"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text1_login"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/1_line"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1_delivery"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:shadowRadius="10.0"
                android:text="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2_delivery"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text1_delivery"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:text="Delivery"
                android:textColor="@color/add_contact_selected"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1_payment"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:shadowRadius="10.0"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2_payment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text1_payment"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                android:text="Payment"
                android:textColor="@color/add_contact_selected"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Update:** add the horizontal line between circles:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1_login"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowRadius="10.0"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1_login"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/1_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1_login" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/2_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text1_delivery" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1_delivery"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:shadowRadius="10.0"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/22_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1_delivery" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2_delivery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1_delivery"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Delivery"
        android:textColor="@color/add_contact_selected"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/3_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text1_payment" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1_payment"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowRadius="10.0"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2_payment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1_payment"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Payment"
        android:textColor="@color/add_contact_selected"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks.. working fine.. But One problem is unable to view the line.

Comment: Change his color or increase the height of your line ( the View).

Comment: It is visible. but stays below the layout. But I need in the middle of two circle.

Comment: I need horizontal separator. that joins two circle.

Comment: @User hope this is what you want, otherwise post a photo to show your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

To align views horizontally , you should use Linear Layout with horizontal orientation and assign weights to each child views.

Check this example which i have written using your layout -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_relative"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#007DD7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowRadius="10.0"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1_delivery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:shadowRadius="10.0"
        android:text="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/add_contact_selected"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw all the answers people who has suggest to use `LinearLayout`.One thing you have to know very clearly.By using the Relative or Linear we can achieve all the layout design.

First you have to analyse which design will be good.Implementation may be depends on three things.

```
1.Easy designing
2.Layout performance
3.How much you know about attributes of layout.
```

My suggestion also Linear only for your implementation but some times multiple inner linear layout will cause performance issue and this also you should aware of it.

How we are developing the code is not important,how we are optimizing the code is very important.